# How can I stop axios from retrying the request after 2 mins

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I have developed a nodejs server and react client application. The client requests an information from server using axios. This information has to be retrieved from a database and takes approx 5 mins. But the client retries the request exactly after 2 mins. How do I ask the client to wait for 5 mins.

client code

```
  axios.get(apiServer + 'teradata/'+table).then( (resp) => {
    console.log(resp.data.data)
    )
```

In server, I tried below. But nothing works.

```
server.on('connection', function(socket) {
    //Teradata takes too long to respond. Set timeoute to 3 mins
    socket.setTimeout(0);
  })

server.on('connection', function(socket) {
    //Teradata takes too long to respond. Set timeoute to 3 mins
    socket.setTimeout(60 * 6 * 1000); 
    // 30 second timeout. Change this as you see fit.
  })
```

Update:
On further debugging, I see that
1. the retry originates from browser. because, retry happens in firefox, but not in chrome.
2. the connection disconnects exactly at 2 mins. This leads to firefox to retry.

I used the following code in express js and saw that it indeed disconnects. But I don't know who disconnects it. Is it axios or express js?

```
req.on("close", function() {
    console.log('request closed unexpectedly')
  });

  req.on("end", function() {
    console.log('equest ended normally')
  });
```

Comment: Are you just wanting to set the timeout for axios? https://github.com/axios/axios#axioscreateconfig or https://github.com/axios/axios#config-order-of-precedence

Comment: I am not sure if you had research the axios doc, please check this https://github.com/axios/axios
You can create a new instance of axios with a custom config.

axios.create([config])
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api/',
  timeout: 1000,
  headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar'}
});

Comment: I am quite sure the server is closing the connection. I would have a look here https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/http.html#http_server_settimeout_msecs_callback . The default value is set to 2 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation you can create an instance of axios and configure timeout too.

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api/',
  timeout: 5000,
  headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar'}
});
```

Comment: I tried it and still have the same problem. One thing I noticed that, even after adding timeout, there is no change in headers. Not sure if timeout header had to be added